# 2-column alignment of equations: left-center

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, subequations

It's a long time since I try to align equations centerly with a prefix on the very left of the page.
I was able to develop a basic version of it using `IEEEeqnarray` of `IEEEtran` class, but since I'm writing the document to a different journal, I cannot use that enviroment. I tried several combinations of `align`, `aligned,` `gather`, etc. with no success.

The working code developed in `IEEEtran` class is the following:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray} {LC}
    \forall{t} & C_t = F_t+K_t \label{eq:1}\\
    \forall{t,i} & C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} \label{eq:2}\\
    \forall{t,s} & \qquad\qquad C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E\qquad\qquad \label{eq:3}\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

That procuces the image below.

[image]

It is worth noticing that neither this code produce the left column to be exactly on the very left since I had to adapt the spacing using several `\qquad`. How can I reproduce a similar code using standard enviroments?

Moreover, I'd be willing to find a solution to achieve the same result under `subequations` enviroment, similarly to the image below.

[image]

The code of the image is the following

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray} {LC}
\forall{t} & C_t = F_t+K_t \label{eq:1}\\
\forall{t,i} & C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} \IEEEyessubnumber \label{eq:2}\\
\forall{t,s} & \qquad\qquad C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E\qquad\qquad \IEEEyessubnumber \label{eq:3}\\
\forall{t,s} & \qquad\qquad C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E\qquad\qquad \label{eq:4}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this hack, based on `eqparbox`, the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` and a `\mysubequations` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\newenvironment{mysubequations}{\subequations\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}{\endsubequations}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray} {LC}
 \forall{t} & C_t = F_t+K_t \label{eq:1}\\
 \forall{t,i} & C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} \label{eq:2}\\
 \forall{t,s} & \qquad\qquad C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E\qquad\qquad \label{eq:3}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\bigskip
\begin{fleqn}[0.6em]
\begin{mysubequations}
\begin{align}
 & \forall{t} & & \eqmathbox[E]{C_t = F_t+K_t} \label{eq:1} \\
 & \forall{t,i} & & \eqmathbox[E]{C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t}} \label{eq:7}\\
 & \forall{t,s} & & \eqmathbox[E]{C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E} \label{eq:3}
\end{align}
\end{mysubequations}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{align}
 & \forall{t,s} & & \eqmathbox[E]{C_t = \sum_{t'=1}^t A_i + B_{i,t} + C + D + E} \label{eq:4}
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]